# How Debug Embedded Zend framework2 application using Netbeans

Tags: debugging, zend-framework, netbeans-8

I have a zend 1 and zend 2 application, [just inherited last week, developer quit], that are embedded into drupal 6 instance. I want to debug the applications using netbeans, but I can only get the debugger working on the drupal instance.

Drupal and these zend inventory applications are stored in their own folders in my main directory, and the zend apps are tied to drupal using it's/Drupal's permissions settings.

when i click on the link in the side bar that calls the zend 1 and/or 2 application, the debugger does not detect or acknowledge this click and thus does not debug the code, but of course any of the other links that are directly related to the drupal side, debug flawlessly.

For those familiar with netbeans, in your run configuration area, you point to the main folder where your code is stored. When I point to the Drupal folder, I can debug drupal, if I point to the "comstance_zf1_inv_sales" folder [where the zf1 application is located] nothing happens because Drupal is kind of kicking things off.

**NOTE**: the applications [drupal, z1 and z2] work fine together in my local environment when loading drupal and application related pages.

**The questions**:

- what to consider when trying to debug a framework application that is embedded into Drupal 6/7
- Has anyone worked in this type of environment with drupal and been able to debug not only Drupal, but also the embedded application/code base?
- Has anyone had experience configuring netbeans, to debug an embedded application, specifically Zend1 and/or Zend2

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working - for anyone that encounters the same circumstance - in drupal be sure you have the iframe parameters set correctly where you are add your code.  I add my php code in a content type and select the node to phpFilter for the text format type.

Next and this was somethin i didn't know about, go to chrome extension an search for xdebug helper.  Enable it, open up netbeans, go back to your site and click on the debug icon that will appear in your url entry bar.